# Switching multi-language substring positions using regex

Tags: regex, go

Raw input with lithuanian letters:

```
Ą.BČ
Ą.BČ D Ę
Ą. BČ
Ą. BČ D Ę
Ą BČ
Ą BČ D Ę
Examples below should not be affected.
ĄB ČD DĘ
```

Expected result:

```
BČ Ą.
BČ Ą. D Ę
BČ Ą. 
BČ Ą. D Ę
BČ Ą 
BČ Ą D Ę
ĄB ČD DĘ
```

What I've tried:

```
^(.\.? *)([\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}]*)$
With ReplaceAllString substitution like so
$2 $1
```

I have tried various patterns but this is the best I could come up for now.
It manages to capture 1st, 3rd and 5th line and successfully substitute like so:
(Except for some extra spaces at the end of lines)

```
BČ Ą.
Ą.BČ D Ę
BČ Ą. 
Ą. BČ D Ę
BČ Ą 
Ą BČ D Ę
ĄB ČD DĘ
```

Explanation:

> There is a set of data with varying entries of the underlying basic
> structure `[FIRST NAME FIRST LETTER][LASTNAME]` which I want to ideally
> bring to `[LASTNAME][SPACE][FIRST NAME FIRST LETTER][DOT]?`

Link to regex101:
[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/R4WWiQ/1)

Final solution:

```
^([\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}](?:\. *| +))([\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}]+)
    With ReplaceAllString substitution like so
    $2 $1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example data, you can omit the anchor `$` and match either a dot followed by optional spaces, or 1 or more spaces.

To prevent an empty match for the character class, you can repeat it 1 or more times using `+` instead of `*`

```
^(.(?:\. *| +))([\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}]+)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5CeXuS/1)

**Note** that the `.` can match any char including a space. You might also change the dot to a single `[\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}]`

Comment: I see, so by using `?:` inside brackets you match the expression but do not capture it. And by leaving out the anchor I can still specify that the desired pattern must start from the first group, am I right?

Comment: @papshmeare The `(?:` is indeed a non capture group, where the alternation matches either a dot and optional spaces, or 1+ spaces so that  `ĄB` in the last example is not matched as there should be at least a single char between them. Due to the anchor `$` in your pattern, you can not match `Ą.BČ D Ę` as the pattern will not account for the last 2 characters due to the missing spaces. If you would add a space, you would match too much. See https://regex101.com/r/ot1wfI/1

Comment: Unfortunately, playing around with exactly that extra space in second group took quite a bit of my time, but it is now clear to me with the introduction to non-capture groups, I should spend some more time reading the docs, thank you for your response!